# Batch merge files from a list to another one and get a result file name according to the current file

Tags: batch-file

In a directory I have several files with the same extension (.tmp)
I want to merge each file with a known one and set the result file name as the name of the .tmp file.

I made this, but doesn't work (I do not understand what I'm doing... not used to dos batches)

```
for /R "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Clients\CBA\Export" %%f in ("*.tmp") do (

copy/b "some path\SACF4_TL.dbf"+ "%%f" "some path the same where is the .tmp file\%%~nI.dbf"

)
```

I'm sure it's simple to do it but lost too much time on it right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /R "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Clients\CBA\Export" %%f in ("*.tmp") do (
    copy /b "some path\SACF4_TL.dbf" + "%%~ff" "%%~dpnf.dbf"
)
```

Where `%%~ff` is the full path to the file pointed by `%%f` and `%%~dpnf` is the drive, path and name of the file pointed by `%%f`